# Short way to apply a function to all elements in a list in golang

Tags: go

Suppose I would like to apply a function to every element in a list, and then put the resulting values in another list so I can immediately use them. In python, I would do something like this:

```py
list = [1,2,3]
str = ', '.join(multiply(x, 2) for x in list)
```

In Go, I do something like this:

```
list := []int{1,2,3}
list2 := []int

for _,x := range list {
    list2 := append(list2, multiply(x, 2))
}

str := strings.Join(list2, ", ")
```

Is it possible to do this in a shorter way?

Comment: what you're looking for is a `map` function. (as opposed to the `map` datatype that's analogous to Python's `dict`)

Comment: Thanks Adam, any idea where i could find them? Is it part of the standard liberaries? I can't find much about it...

Comment: I threw an answer up, but googling for "golang map function" will give you more information. The short answer is No, there is no such function in golang

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would do exactly as you did, with a few tweaks to fix typos

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    list := []int{1,2,3}

    var list2 []string
    for _, x := range list {
        list2 = append(list2, strconv.Itoa(x * 2))  // note the = instead of :=
    }

    str := strings.Join(list2, ", ")
    fmt.Println(str)
}
```

Answer (score 22):

This is an old question, but was the top hit in my Google search, and I found information that I believe will be helpful to the OP and anyone else who arrives here, looking for the same thing.

There is a shorter way, although you have to write the map function yourself.

In go, `func` is a type, which allows you to write a function that accepts as input the subject slice and a function, and which iterates over that slice, applying that function.

See the `Map` function near the bottom of this Go by Example page : https://gobyexample.com/collection-functions

I've included it here for reference:

```
func Map(vs []string, f func(string) string) []string {
    vsm := make([]string, len(vs))
    for i, v := range vs {
        vsm[i] = f(v)
    }
    return vsm
}
```

You then call it like so:

```
fmt.Println(Map(strs, strings.ToUpper))
```

So, yes:  The shorter way you are looking for exists, although it is not built into the language itself.

Comment: The reason it's not built-in is that Go has no generics (yet?).  So you have to write a different Map for each type.

Comment: After reading the comment above, I was wondering if reflection, interfaces can be used, then I found answer below. Surreal.

Comment: @Anubhav : note that an `interface` is not the same as a "generic", as it's typically meant in programming languages; the other answer's `Map()` function has a result of a different type than the input, which might or might not be suitable for specific circumstances; yes, an `interface` can in some ways be treated like other types, but not in every way, so use the `interface`-based `Map()` with that in mind

Answer (score 19):

With go1.18+ you can write a much cleaner generic Map function:

```
func Map[T, V any](ts []T, fn func(T) V) []V {
    result := make([]V, len(ts))
    for i, t := range ts {
        result[i] = fn(t)
    }
    return result
}
```

Usage, e.g:

```
input := []int{4, 5, 3}
outputInts := Map(input, func(item int) int { return item + 1 })
outputStrings := Map(input, func(item int) string { return fmt.Sprintf("Item:%d", item) })
```

Answer (score 18):

I've created a small utility package with `Map`and `Filter` methods now that generics have been introduced in 1.18 :)

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sa-/slicefunk

Example usage

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    sf "github.com/sa-/slicefunk"
)

func main() {
    original := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    newArray := sf.Map(original, func(item int) int { return item + 1 })
    newArray = sf.Map(newArray, func(item int) int { return item * 3 })
    newArray = sf.Filter(newArray, func(item int) bool { return item%2 == 0 })
    fmt.Println(newArray)
}
```

Comment: Any chance for the Go standard library to have a built-in analog?

Answer (score 5):

Found a way to define a generic map array function

```
func Map(t interface{}, f func(interface{}) interface{} ) []interface{} {
    switch reflect.TypeOf(t).Kind() {
    case reflect.Slice:
        s := reflect.ValueOf(t)
        arr := make([]interface{}, s.Len())
        for i := 0; i < s.Len(); i++ {
            arr[i] = f(s.Index(i).Interface())
        }
        return arr
    }
    return nil
}

origin := []int{4,5,3}
newArray := Map(origin, func(item interface{}) interface{} { return item.(int) + 1})
```

Comment: That's a bit terse. Using two advanced concepts in go, namely `interface{}` and `reflect` explanation should be most welcome. I suppose you 'found' _out_ how to do it, not 'found' _it somewhere and copied it_.

Comment: After reading the answer above, I thought of using reflect and interface, and how reflection might slow it down, scroll down a little, and behold.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [lo](https://github.com/samber/lo#map)'s Map in order to quickly apply a function to all elements. For example, in order to multiply by 2 and convert to string, you can use:

```
l := lo.Map[int, string]([]int{1, 2, 3, 4}, func(x int, _ int) string { return strconv.Itoa(x * 2) })
```

Then you can convert back to a comma delimited string like so:
`strings.Join(l, ",")`